# LaTeX undefined control sequence

Tags: latex

I'm working on some homework, and I was checking to make sure my code would compile to a PDF. I continually get an error that reads :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \urcorner
l.74 (($\urcorner
$
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Here is my code:

[image]

Here is my preamble:

[image]

Comment: Please include the actual code in your question rather than a screenshot of the code.

Answer (score 1):

`\urcorner` is defined by [`amssymb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amscls), which you didn't include in your preamble. So, add

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

to your preamble and you'll be able to use `\urcorner` (and `\ulcorner`, `\llcorner` and `\lrcorner`).

Further to your document construction. I'd use an `enumerate` environment to set your questions. Perhaps also use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to format the labels to suit your needs:

```
\usepackage{amssymb,enumitem}
...
\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)}]
  \item <some item>
  \item <some other item>
  ...
  \item <last item>
\end{enumerate}
```

*Never* just use `\\` to end a line.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem solving https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85024/symbols-in-math-mode

Why don't you use

```
\begin{enumerate}
   \item First item
   \item Second item ...
 \end{enumerate}
```

for numeric listing?